# calculating first quartile for a numeric column in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a newbie in spark/scala. This is what I'm doing to calculate the first quartile of a csv file

```
val column= sc.textFile("test.txt").map(_.split(",")(2)).flatMap(_.split(",")).map((_.toDouble))
val total = column.count.toDouble
val upper=(total+1)/4
val upper2= scala.math.ceil(upper).toInt
```

I'm not really sure how to sort the column other than adding a Key Value Pair. 
all I need is to take the last 2 values for the quartiles, after they are sorted. But i'm forced to create a key value pair.

```
val quartiles = column.map((_,1)).sortByKey(true).take(upper2)
val first_quartile =0
if(upper % upper.toInt >0){
   first_quartile = quartiles(upper.toInt-1) 
}else{
   first_quartile = (quartiles(upper2-1) +(quartiles(upper2-2))/2
}
```

This works, but it will leave me with an annoying key value pair. how do i revert back to just 1 column, instead of 2 (e.g. the key value pair)

Comment: You can discard the dummy values via `rdd.keys`.

Comment: Is there a reason/requirement to use Spark?

Comment: not really a requirement, just starting to learn spark and scala. it's wicked fast. :D

Answer (score 8):

Was just doing this myself. I started out writing a function to compute the median, but found it was faster and easier to get quantiles by casting my RDD as a DataFrame and querying it with SQL. Here's a self-contained example:

```
  // construct example RDD
  val rows = Seq(3, 1, 5, 1, 9, 2, 2)
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(rows)

  // construct Dataframe
  case class MedianDF(value: Long)
  val df = rdd.map(row => MedianDF(row.toLong)).toDF 

  // register the table and then query for your desired percentile
  df.registerTempTable("table")
  sqlContext.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(value, 0.5) FROM table").show()
```

Which returns 2, the median. Similarly, if you want the first quartile just pass 0.25 to PERCENTILE:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(value, 0.25) FROM table").show()
```

Comment: Hi Eric, what version of spark did you used and what sql context are you using is it spark sqlcontext or hive sqlcontext can you share import statements too