# Scala - First quartile, third quartile, and IQR from spark SQLContext dataframe without Hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe:

```
data.show()
+--------+------+------------------+
|   Count|  mean|             stdev|
+--------+------+------------------+
|       5|  6337| 1684.569470220803|
|       3|  7224| 567.8250904401182|
|     330| 20280|23954.260831863092|
|      42| 26586|  32957.9072313323|
...
|      49| 23422|21244.094701798418|
|       4| 36949| 8616.596311769514|
|      35| 20915|14971.559603562522|
|      33| 20874|16657.756963894684|
|      14| 22698|15416.614921307082|
|      25| 19100| 12342.11627585264|
|      27| 21879|21363.736895687238|
+--------+------+------------------+
```

Without using Hive, I want to get the first quartile, second quartile and the IQR (interquartile range) for column "mean".

Other solutions seem to use Hive which everyone might not have access to.

[Hive Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519549/how-to-calculate-median-in-spark-sqlcontext-for-column-of-data-type-double)

[Hive Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376370/calculating-first-quartile-for-a-numeric-column-in-spark)

[Solution for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-using-spark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to first note that this seems to be a pretty expensive solution but I get precisely what I want wihtout using Hive. If you are able to use Hive definitely do it because it couldn't be any easier.

I ended up using commons-math3 jar. The trick to using it was getting the data out of the dataframe and into an array for consumption by the math3 library. I solved that from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000646/how-to-convert-a-column-of-dataframe-to-a-list-in-apache-spark). You may have to play with the "asInstanceOf" based on the datatype of the column.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive._

// Turn dataframe column into an Array[Long]
val mean = data.select("mean").rdd.map(row => row(0).asInstanceOf[Long]).collect()

// Create the math3 object and add values from the
// mean array to the descriptive statistics array
val arrMean = new DescriptiveStatistics()
genericArrayOps(mean).foreach(v => arrMean.addValue(v))

// Get first and third quartiles and then calc IQR
val meanQ1 = arrMean.getPercentile(25)
val meanQ3 = arrMean.getPercentile(75)
val meanIQR = meanQ3 - meanQ1
```